# engine not cranking, it only gives click sound as I try to start

Tags: engine, starting, hyundai, no-crank-no-start, i20

2009 Hyundai i20 engine died while driving and it is now not cranking. I have changed spark plugs but in vain

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you able to see lights and are the clusters working on the dash? Is the battery or check engine light lit? We need more data to work with here. Your question is vague. All we know is that you swapped the spark plugs (but no symptoms of loose or incorrectly gapped plugs). I can only think a sensor or other electrical unit is disconnected. Hardly anything to work on here. Failed alternator, or discontented cord to the CEL.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is, your battery is too dead to run the engine, which could be caused from a bad alternator. You can check the voltage at the battery using a digital multimeter (DMM). It should be around 12.5vdc or better. If it is less than this, try charging it and seeing if that allows you to start and run the engine. If it doesn't take a charge, then you'll need to replace the battery. If it will take a charge, you need to test the voltage while the engine is running. It should be between 13.5-14.2vdc (or there about). If the voltage is still at battery voltage while running, your alternator is bad.

Comment: If the battery is good, you might also check that the terminals are clean and tightly connected. Sometimes a loose connection can provide so little current that the car will only click and won't start.

Answer (score 1):

Check the starter motor is it well attached to the bell housing i once experienced the same problem but on a Mercedes Benz and later found out i had loose starter bolts.

If it bolted nice and tight then the problem might be within the starter motor maybe a faulty starter solenoid .
Then check all the wiring harness

Comment: Wiring harness is my bet here as well from the extremely limited data ‘spark plugs’.

Answer (score -1):

Connecting rod may have broken. Checking if any symptoms like oil leaks, crank noise in engaged gear might ascertain cause